# Flash storage on the GPIO?

Tags: hardware, storage

I was thinking, if this possible to connect a flash storage on the GPIO,
I know that I could just use one of the USB ports and attach something similar to [this](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Verbatim-StorenStay-Nano-16GB-16G-USB-Flash-Drive-Mobile-Car-Tablet-Mini-Disk-/331057403758?pt=UK_Computing_FlashDrives_SM&hash=item4d148f176e), but that will take one of the ports, which I do not want to do.

> Is there any type of storage( with a size of at least a 1GB), that could be connected on the GPIO pins?

Keys to the best solution:

- Does not suggest a USB hub
- Does not take any USB ports
- Fits inside the case or there is a case that could contain it
- It can be plug and play (so it is easy to be replaced)
- Does not require an extension board
- Fits inside a regular case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an extant solution, but it fails one of your criteria:

- *Does not require an extension board*

… although you could just have it on flying leads from the GPIO. The idea doesn't seem to have had much work done on it since the early days of the Raspberry Pi.

I'm suggesting that an SPI-based [Micro SD adaptor](https://www.pjrc.com/teensy/sd_adaptor.html) *should* be able to work plugged into the GPIO. It's not going to be very fast, it will likely need kernel drivers, and you're probably going to have to do some magic incantations to stop the system croaking if you pull it out of a running Raspberry Pi. But these devices work well with µcontrollers, and the Raspberry Pi has all the right data lines. It's just a small matter of programming to get it going …

Comment: Thanks very much for the light of hope, will be perfect if you could recommend me some tut or some guide as I am more of the software than hardware type (although I am confident enough to try)

Comment: You can also just solder some wires to a microSD to SD card adapter. A quick google bring up the thread http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=72&t=59395